# Why only Seven elements in a Tuple in C# 4.0, with the eighth being another tuple?

Tags: .net, f#, c#-4.0

In F# the syntax sugar hides the CLR implementation, why not in C# 4.0?

Comment: You're essentially asking why C# doesn't have special tuple syntax like F# does.

Comment: @Judah: Yeah, that's what he's asking. It's what I tried to answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UPDATE: This answer was written over a decade ago. A syntax for tuples was added to C# 7.0.

---

We considered adding a syntactic sugar for tuples. I think everyone agrees that it's a nice feature, but it simply didn't fit into the budget.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I think that closes this question nicely :)

Comment: May be something to add in 4.1 ? :)

Comment: Eric, have you seen de Icaza's work on tuples over here: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Dec-23.html?

Answer (score 3):

It seems unlikely that someone using the features of the C# language to their appropriate level would require a Tuple containing more than 7 elements, especially given the existing and established techniques for problem solving and C#'s primarily OO approach to solution development.

F#, on the other hand, is a language designed to be primarily functional.  As such, it does things in a primarily functional way and the language features are focused toward that primary concept.  Resultantly, it made a lot more sense to spend the resources required to supply the language feature you're requesting in F# than it did in C#.

Remember that [all new language features start with 100 points against them](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx).  :)

Comment: Yes I understand where your coming from, but the underlying structure in the CLR is exactly the same, why surface this like for like in C# and hide in syntax sugar in F#? Something to do with the position of C# being closer to the CLR maybe, wild guess from my part, was hoping for a definitive answer. One of thise niggly things   you come across that doesn't seem right.

Comment: It's not exposed with the syntactic sugar in C# because that's a significant language feature which would need definition and implementation and starts at minus 100 points.  Other language features, e.g. dynamic, clearly received priority on that front.

Comment: Why the esoteric structure though, nightmare to work with in C#. Have you tried working with a 20 element tuple in c#, and to automate it means coming up with a new loop thing that looks for tuples appended to the end of tuples.

Comment: If you have a tuple with 20 elements, perhaps you should consider a different data structure or a more appropriate language (like F#).  You could also trivially implement your own `Tuple<T1, T2, ..., T20>` with 20 elements (it's not that hard) and use it.

Comment: Please, do not create your own Tuple type with 20 elements... think of the children.  @WeNeedAnswers, have you heard of this thing called a "class?"

Comment: funny, I thought a tuple was a class in the CLR?

Comment: Why create an object that is used basically to store state without methods acting on the state? Way too much overhead there, I would much rather see something light weight in the syntax. How many times do we create a class that stores state, then put this into a generic list?, I would rather use an array of tuples, and cut the chaff. Like using an F1 car to go to the shops.

Comment: Sorry, but even in F# I would consider a 20-element tuple Bad Style. Use a record type, please!

Answer (score 3):

The following is a good MSDN article by Matt Ellis on the Base Class Libraries (BCL) team that goes through exactly what they were thinking on this and some other key issues regarding the `Tuple` classes.

Building Tuple: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942829.aspx

Due to the design of .NET generics, the number of generic type parameters is fixed at compile time. Therefore, they had to pick some number of generic parameters to do the implementation. The article explains that it is patterned on the existing `Action` and `Func` delegates. Ironically, additional delegates for `Action` and `Func` were subsequently added taking the number of generic type parameters up to 16, but the `Tuple` developers did not follow suit.

Comment: yes read that. Could have hidden the CLR type though. They have had the tuple type hanging around for over 3 years, why such a shot gun approach to something that could be very useful and important if treated right.

Answer (score 3):

This is speculation on my part, but I suspect that another factor is that F# has a rather elaborate mechanism for storing language specific metadata.  There needs to be some way to distinguish between a "7-tuple the last element of which is a 3-tuple" and a 9-tuple, even though they are encoded in the same way in terms of .NET types.  F# accomplishes this via custom metadata blobs, just as it uses metadata to store constraints which are more expressive than those which are built in to .NET (e.g. enum or member constraints).  C# doesn't have a history of storing elaborate, language-specific metadata with assemblies, some form of which would be a necessary prerequisite for handling extended tuples (although a custom attribute might suffice in this case).

Comment: nice answer. So F# is just syntax sugar all the way, whilst c# is "take me or leave me, this is what it is.".

Answer (score 2):

Well, the simple answer to your question is that C# doesn't provide *any* syntactic sugar for working with tuples, so there is no way it could hide nesting of tuples when there are more than 8 elements.

Of course, I guess you're actually asking why there is no syntactic sugar for working with tuples in C# 4.0. I think the main reason why it isn't there is that it encourages lightweight style of programming which isn't usually supported in C# (but works very well for F# programmers).

- In F#, it is perfectly fine to write code that looks like this:

  ```
  let parseRecord rc = 
    // some code to parse the argument
  let (left, top, wid, hgt, str) = parseRecord record
  ```

  However, this code is reasonable only in the early phase of the development pocess (when writing some prototype and experimenting) or if the functionality is very localized (used within one function). In a more evolved version of the code, you would probably replace this with some more suitable data structure (e.g. F# record) to make the code more readable and I think this is what people *typically* do in F#
- On the other hand, if C# propgrammer wrote something like the following code, people would be quite scared how unreadable the code is:

  ```
  { int, int, int, int, string } ParseRecord(string record) { 
     // some code to parse the argument
  }
  var (left, top, wid, hgt, str) = ParseRecord(record);
  ```

  So, I think the overall style of programming in C# is simply less suitable for lightweight features as tuples and pattern matching on tuples, because it doesn't work that well with the rest of the language.

Of course, there may be some nicer way to support this in C# and it may be added in the future, however I think that the integration of this feature would be more complicated than in F#. Also, *anonymous types* serve similar purpose as tuples (but only locally), so in some cases, you don't really need tuples in C#.

Comment: Wow, seeing that C# version of tuples typed out really is pretty scary. :p

Comment: @Tanzelax Gets worse with larger tuples, and then trying to reference the elements, with tuples inside of tuples.